# Localization of a finitely generated module is trivial iff its annihilator is nontrivial

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

I have a problem on Atiyah and MacDonald's commutative algebra book, the exercise 3.1:

> Let $S$ be a multiplicatively closed subset of a ring $A$ and $M$ a
>   finitely generated $A$ - module. Prove that $S^{-1}M = 0$ iff there
>   exists $s \in S$ such that $sM = 0$.

I know the correct proof, but I have confusion about the following proof of the sufficiency:

> Let $S^{-1}M = 0$, then $\frac{m}{t}=0=\frac{0}{1} , \forall m \in M,
>  \forall t \in S$. So $\exists s \in S$ such that $s(m \ast 1-0 \ast t)=0$,
>   that is $sm=0, \forall m \in M$ $\Rightarrow $ $sM=0$.

I am not sure it is right. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have shows that for a fixed $m \in M$, there is $s \in S$ so that $sm = 0$. It does not show that $sM = 0$. To show this, you need to use the fact that $M$ is finitely generated. Apply what you have to a generating set of $M$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know what you mean.

Comment: @Sheldon Happy to help!